# How to use operators so that they exclude zero?

Tags: php, math, operators

In my database I have "maximum files" but I would like to set it at 0 for unlimited.

Therefore I need a way to

```
if ($count >= $max){
    //a value of 0 in $max should not be here
} else {
   //but here
}
```

Is this possible or do I have to create an exclusion for 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($max && ($count >= $max)) ....
```

Comment: although this is a clearer code, its not self documented. A person has to spend more than 1 second to read this and understand this one with the logic of your code (which is allow all 0 )

Answer (score 2):

```
if (($max !== 0) && ($count >= $max) ){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($max) && $count >= $max ) { ...
```